# Get progress of UINavigationController swipe back

Tags: ios, swift

I have two `viewControllers`, both are part of a `UINavigationController`.
From `View1` I can tap a `UITableViewCell` and go to `View2`, from `View2` I can swipe back to `View1`.

I would like to know how I can get the progress of this transition, and I have been unsuccessful with the following:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(going))
}
@objc func going(){
        print(self.transitionCoordinator?.percentComplete)
}
```

That `going` function is called a lot during the transition, but that print statement just prints `nil`. I tried with other view controller (both View1 and the parent nav controller) to no avail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe navigationController?. transitionCoordinator...

Comment: That prints an Optional(0.0), at the start, and then nil after that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what seems to work:

```
    private var currentTransitionCoordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator?

    @objc private func onGesture(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        switch sender.state {
        case .began, .changed:
            if let ct = navigationController?.transitionCoordinator {
                currentTransitionCoordinator = ct
            }
        case .cancelled, .ended:
            currentTransitionCoordinator = nil
        case .possible, .failed:
            break
        }

        if let currentTransitionCoordinator = currentTransitionCoordinator {
            print(currentTransitionCoordinator.percentComplete)
        }

    }
```

After you let go there is no way to get progress though. I tried preserving the coordinator for a bit longer and printing values on timer but I get a crash even.

Anyway, I assume this is what you need.

**TEST SCENARIO:**

Create a new project and navigate to main storyboard. Add a navigation controller and set its root view controller to `ViewController` in storyboard (remove the autogenerated root).

Then go to ViewController.swift and overwrite it with following:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if let controller = navigationController, controller.viewControllers.count <= 1 { // Present it first time only
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            let newController = ViewController()
            newController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(newController, action: #selector(onGesture))
            navigationController?.pushViewController(newController, animated: true)
        }
    }

    private var currentTransitionCoordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator?

    @objc private func onGesture(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        switch sender.state {
        case .began, .changed:
            if let ct = navigationController?.transitionCoordinator {
                currentTransitionCoordinator = ct
            }
        case .cancelled, .ended:
            currentTransitionCoordinator = nil
        case .possible, .failed:
            break
        }

        if let currentTransitionCoordinator = currentTransitionCoordinator {
            print(currentTransitionCoordinator.percentComplete)
        }

    }

}
```

You should be able to see percentage printed out as you drag your finger, dismissing currently pushed view controller.

Comment: Thank you, but the progress never gets printed for me

Comment: @Will Ensure you add the correct method to gesture recognizer. I changed its name.

Comment: Thank you Matic, I was able to get it to work pre-edit. Thanks for your help!