# Get UIViewController position on swipe dismissing

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-animation

What is the best way to 'listen' for ViewController position on its dismissing?

For example user begins swipe from left side of screen dismissing top ViewController, and while this controller moves from left to right i get this top ViewController position/offset from left?

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787759/get-progress-of-uinavigationcontroller-swipe-back

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes i found solution in question you mentioned above.